# Yoghurt maker getting up to 54.2C/129F. Is that normal?

Tags: yogurt

I just got a new yoghurt maker, nothing fancy just a heating bed with a lid and jars. But after 12 hours passed, I noticed the jars were too hot, and after testing them they were at  54.2C/129F. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

The temperature range for making yogurt is about 108-112F (42-45C), so that sounds a bit hot.  Maybe contact the manufacturer.